# Hangman from Python 2 to Python 3

Tags: python

```
sRealWord = input("Write the Hangman Word in Capital Letters: ") 
lShownWord = ["_"] * len(sRealWord) 
sInput = ""
iAllowedGuesses = 10  
iLetterNumber = 0   #was []
iRightGuesses = 0   #was [] 


print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")
print("Let the Game Begin!")
print("Type END to close game, or complete your 10 guesses")

while(sInput != "END" and iAllowedGuesses != 0): 
    print("The word you're looking for is: " + str(lShownWord)) ##FIXED
    print("You have: " + str(iAllowedGuesses) + " guesses left") ##FIXED 
    sInput = input("Enter letter in Capital Letters: ")
    iAllowedGuesses -= 1 ##VALUE 1 ##FIXED

while(iLetterNumber < len(sRealWord)) : **###THIS IS NOT WORKING**
   if (sRealWord[iLetterNumber] == sInput) : 
       lShownWord[iLetterNumber] == sInput 
       iRightGuesses += 1    
       iLetterNumber += 1 
       iLetterNumber = 0
   elif (iRightGuesses == len(sRealWord)): ###**THIS IS NOT WORKING**
       print("Woho!, You've won!")
   elif (iAllowedGuesses == 0):
       print("You are out of guesses, Game Over!") ###fixed
       break
```

I decided to take an old Hangman code from Python 2 and migrate into Python 3 for practice.

The lines that I think are preventing the code from working correctly are commented out and in bold.

***What am I missing or doing wrong in the code or those lines that needs to be done differently or fixed in order for the game to work?***

FYI

The output for running out of guesses is working. Although, the output of getting right guesses is not working, therefore, when you get the word right it just continues as if they are wrong.

Comment: try change `elif`s for `if`s

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues that I see. But none seem to have to do with python2 vs python3.

1. You probably want to assign the `sInput` to the `lShownWord[iLetterNumber]` if it is correct. For that, you need only a single `=`.
2. There is no point in incrementing `iLetterNumber` right before setting it to zero. I assume what you want to do is check every letter of the word, every time the user enters a word. You can do that with a while loop and resetting the variable manually, but it's more idiomatic and slightly leass error prone with a for loop. The for loop resets the counter variable automatically, and increments it every loop iteration.
3. Careful with the indentation. You don't want to first have the user try `iAllowedGuesses` times before showing the correct characters. Both the while loop and the ifs were in the wrong place. And once you put the `if` statements to the correct level of indentation, `elif` does not make sense there anymore.
4. You probably also want to `break` if the user has won.

This leaves us with this code.

```py
sRealWord = input("Write the Hangman Word in Capital Letters: ") 
lShownWord = ["_"] * len(sRealWord) 
sInput = ""
iAllowedGuesses = 10  
iRightGuesses = 0   #was [] 


print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")
print("Let the Game Begin!")
print("Type END to close game, or complete your 10 guesses")

while(sInput != "END" and iAllowedGuesses != 0): 
    print("The word you're looking for is: " + str(lShownWord)) ##FIXED
    print("You have: " + str(iAllowedGuesses) + " guesses left") ##FIXED 
    sInput = input("Enter letter in Capital Letters: ")
    iAllowedGuesses -= 1 ##VALUE 1 ##FIXED

    for iLetterNumber in range(len(sRealWord)) :
       if (sRealWord[iLetterNumber] == sInput) : 
           lShownWord[iLetterNumber] = sInput 
           iRightGuesses += 1    
    if (iRightGuesses == len(sRealWord)):
       print("Woho!, You've won!")
       break
    if (iAllowedGuesses == 0):
       print("You are out of guesses, Game Over!")
       break
```

Comment: You were spot on with the assumptions. Thank you very much for the explanations and the clarification between my assumption of Python 2 vs 3. Your answer and explanations were and are super helpful.

Comment: Happy to help! I was thinking I could maybe add a paragraph about how you could've figured this out on your own, but there aren't really tricks that I've used other than being a second pair of eyes reading your code